# Friendly urls in PHP and htaccess for English and Spanish

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a website in English and Spanish, every language has its own folder for example:

```
news.com/en/ for English
news.com/es/ for Spanish
```

The latest news list is displayed with some short parts of the news at:

```
news.com/en/latest-news.php for English
news.com/es/ultimas-noticias.php for Spanish
```

When the user click on some article to read the entire article they are linked to read the full article (using the stored slug in MySQL) from here like this (for example):

```
news.com/en/general/news/europe/2022/10/22/this-is-a-nice-title
```

All articles are using the following pages to GET the slugs:

```
news.com/en/read-article.php for English
news.com/es/leer-noticia.php for Spanish
```

On these pages the script query MySQL to search for the slug and displays the full article. The problem is that I am getting no results by some reason I don't understand.

If I move to the ROOT the files:

```
news.com/read-article.php for English
news.com/leer-noticia.php for Spanish
```

Then it works fine, but adding these files to subfolders I get no results.

Important is to say that the slugs are saved in MySQL like this:

```
general/news/europe/2022/10/22/this-is-a-nice-title
```

That because they looks better than with dashes and the date is the date of publishment so it changes for every article.

Here is my .htaccess code created for these subfolders:

**UPDATED: The problem is here in htaccess only and is still not fully solved, even if I answered my own question**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(en)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ $1/read-article.php?id=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^(es)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ $1/leer-noticia.php?id=$2 [L]
```

Any idea where is the problem here?

Comment: If the original URL path that the client requests is `/english/general/news/europe/2022/10/22/this-is-a-nice-title`, then the two rules you have shown would not match to begin with.

Comment: _"they are linked from here like this"_, _"While in reality they are linked and go to the following files"_ - now which one is it, what is the actual URL you output for your links on the client side? It sounds like you are not differentiating between "linked to" and "internally rewritten to" here in your description, which makes the whole thing harder to understand.

Comment: `https://example.com/english/` and `https://example.com/en/` are two different things ...

Comment: I answered my own question but the answer needs some pro-advise

Answer (score 0):

For these looking for help because they have the same problem and I am sure there are many:

I could fix it in a very lucky but for sure not professional way, it is maybe the wrong way but it is working. There are many similar questions without answers here on this site, so it seems like in general there is not so much knowledge about htaccess.

The solution I found is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^en/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ /en/read-article?slug=$1  [L]
RewriteRule ^en/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ /en/leer-noticia?slug=$1  [L]
```

So you can have your website in many languages, every language in a subfolder, but even if you are running just one single language website and using subfolders, then you are for sure going to need this help,  you just run this .htaccess and it will work (edit with your file names obviously)

Now what we for sure are going to need is to read some more about the [L] in the code, there are many other codes like this:

I don't understand the following commands, neither if they are needed but you looking for help can for sure find it out or maybe some people here can share knowledge with us:

```
DirectoryIndex home.php  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
[L]
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
[QSA]
```

Nobody else answered this question, it is the same with most questions about .htaccess and friendly-urls but here is at least something, unprofessional but I share some small noobie knowledge anyway because this is the main idea of this community, not everybody is a pro, but we can all share knowledge. If there is a better answer I will for sure mark it as correct

Comment: If you are using directives that you yourself state that you don't understand, then why don't you simply take a look into the documentation of those directives? https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html